# initialization of properties in the constructor

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, constructor

I have a class with few properties in it and for few reasons i have to initialize them in the constructor. i did so like this

```
public DataBuilder(IResources Resources)
        {
            _resources = Resources;
            // pre initializing data so request load faster after the first request
            var providerList = ProviderList;
            var publisherList = PublisherList;
            var applicationsList = ApplicationList;
            var catergoriesList = CategoryList;
            var editionsList = EditionsList;
        }
```

But the team lead told me to think how i can initialize them without assigning them to a variable.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: That doesn't look like it would compile.

Comment: but it does, i have it running on our stable environment :)

Comment: I think you need to set them as properties what you have is scoped to just the constructor and none of the values could be used outside

Comment: OK, it looks like the action of getting from `ProviderList` etc causes something else to happen? Assigning them to a variable is just a means to an end of triggering the get?

Comment: V4Vendeta , i think you misunderstood me , i don't need the values in the constructor , i just need to initialize  the properties ( because they get data ) without assigning them to variables.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth, yes , exactly.

Comment: I guess, currently you're doing the expensive loading in a getter. In that case, if you really want to do it in the constructor, you could implement a setter and say `ProviderList = getProviderList();` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>It'd be nice to know what you are doing in each of the properties, as without that context all of this seems like a code smell.</sub>

If this data load on a property get is expensive enough to warrant "pre-calling" them in a constructor, the **first** thing I'd do is *at least* make them methods:

```
InitializePropertyList();
// etc
```

The reason I tend to favour methods is either when the return value is liable to change on subsequent calls or if the call is expensive (which it will be in your case) - I expect property calls to be cheap.

As for them being in the constructor, this immediately seems like a code smell to me. It seems the code is in the wrong place.

Why not construct the object without any data loading and expose a method to pre-load things?

```
class DataBuilder
{
    public DataBuilder(IResources resources)
    {
        _resources = resources;
    }

    public void PreLoadExpensiveData()
    {
        InitializeProviderList();
        // etc
    }

    private void InitializeProviderList()
    {
        // Put whatever was in get_ProviderList into here 
        // and make the property return just the field.
    }
}
```

I also tend to expect object construction to be cheap. If the constructor has to do a lot, perhaps refactor it so the constructor *asks* for the data instead of getting it itself. Alternatively, use my structure above where constructing the object is fast, but you expose a data loading or initialization method - assuming such a data load action is the *responsibility* of the object.

Comment: The properties are returning `Dictionary<string,int>`, and now that you mentioned it , I'm not sure i didn't make them functions >_<.
The pre-calling is so they can get their data from the DB , but first call is slow. I'm going to try your solution and see how that goes.
Cheers!

Comment: @Aviatrix My solution won't be any faster, just the code may express what you are trying to do a little more effectively.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with initialization in ctor. Initialize method, OTOH might wind up problematic - it's highly likely that at some point *somebody* will forget to call it.
@Aviatrix: what your team lead *might have* meant, is that `var providerList = ProviderList;` carries no information about what is really happening (pre-loading), and on top of that such code at the first glance, makes no sense to reader. I'd try addressing that.

Comment: @jimmy_keen Database calls in a constructor seem like a target for refactoring in my eyes. Initialization on its own is fine, because that's what the constructor is for. Making database / expensive calls in the constructor seems like a bleeding of concerns, or at the very least the wrong place to do it.